# Slick2D game launches then immediately closes

Tags: java, windows, game-engine, slick2d, kryonet

I've been working with Slick2D and Kryonet to create a pretty basic multi-player RPG. While the server portion and database have been literally just plug and play it seems I'm having trouble with the graphics. Essentially when launch the client I connect to the server just fine, upon a successful connection the actual Game launches. There is no error in particular but it launches to a black screen very briefly before terminating the client.

I was having trouble getting the code to format properly so below is a link to pastebin that contains the code. There are no errors thrown or anything along those lines so I'm not 100% sure what to look for.

[Link to source](http://pastebin.com/fPLefDKA)

Comment: You should use a debugger to step through your code to see where your application is crashing or exiting early.  Then post the code regarding the crash/exit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it ended up being my map file not being able to find the correct terrain sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error with my TiledMap file. Needed to edit the image sources for the tile sets.
Thanks to JNYRanger for suggesting debugging, took a couple tries but was eventually able to catch what was going on.